# Javascript: Map array with objects from another array and return computed array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This might seem trivial but I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

I have an array like below:
**Array 1:**

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2019-03-27",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": [
            5,
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2019-03-28",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": "2019-03-29",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "date": "2019-03-30",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "date": "2019-03-31",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "date": "2019-04-01",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "date": "2019-04-02",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": [
            3
        ]
    }

]
```

Here the `reservations` contains id for which i need to use another array as shown below:

**Array 2:**

```js
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "app": 1,
        "comment": "test 5"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "app": 1,
        "comment": "test 2"
    }
]
```

**Expected:**

I need a way to include Array 2 data inside Array 1 where I use the `id` from `reservations` of Array 1 and pull the corresponding object from Array 2. Finally I need to return Array 1 with these objects added from Array 2 .

I'm using Vue and hope to get this array computed in getters so I can get this in my component and map there directly. If there are any better ways of doing this I'm open to any suggestions

This is what I'm trying to get as output:

`

```
[
        {
          'id': 1,
          'date': '2019-03-27',
          'time': 1,
          'max_tasks': 3,
          'reservations': [
            {
              'id': 5,
              'app': 1,
              'comment': 'test 5'
            },
            {
              'id': 2,
              'app': 1,
              'comment': 'test 2'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'date': '2019-03-28',
          'time': 1,
          'max_tasks': 3,
          'reservations': []
        },
        {
          'id': 3,
          'date': '2019-03-29',
          'time': 1,
          'max_tasks': 3,
          'reservations': []
        },
        {
          'id': 4,
          'date': '2019-03-30',
          'time': 1,
          'max_tasks': 3,
          'reservations': []
        },
        {
          'id': 5,
          'date': '2019-03-31',
          'time': 1,
          'max_tasks': 3,
          'reservations': []
        },
        {
          'id': 6,
          'date': '2019-04-01',
          'time': 1,
          'max_tasks': 3,
          'reservations': []
        },
        {
          'id': 7,
          'date': '2019-04-02',
          'time': 1,
          'max_tasks': 3,
          'reservations': [
            3
          ]
        }
      ]
```

`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please post your Vue attempt, hopefully it will clearly show what you mean by "get this array computed in getters"

Comment: @Cody G. So far I have tried array filter and map methods which does not give what i need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the best solution but give it a try.

```js
let arr1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2019-03-27",
    "time": 1,
    "max_tasks": 3,
    "reservations": [
      5,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2019-03-28",
    "time": 1,
    "max_tasks": 3,
    "reservations": []
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2019-03-29",
    "time": 1,
    "max_tasks": 3,
    "reservations": []
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "date": "2019-03-30",
    "time": 1,
    "max_tasks": 3,
    "reservations": []
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": "2019-03-31",
    "time": 1,
    "max_tasks": 3,
    "reservations": []
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "date": "2019-04-01",
    "time": 1,
    "max_tasks": 3,
    "reservations": []
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "date": "2019-04-02",
    "time": 1,
    "max_tasks": 3,
    "reservations": [
      3
    ]
  }

]
let arr2 = [{
    "id": 5,
    "app": 1,
    "comment": "test 5"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "app": 1,
    "comment": "test 2"
  }
]
arr1.forEach(o => {
  let updatedReverations = []
  o.reservations.forEach(r => {
    updatedReverations.push(arr2.filter(a2 => r === a2.id)[0] || r)
  })
  o.reservations = updatedReverations
})
console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: thanks alot for your response. This works for most part but reservations returns an array or arrays. I require this to be array of objects instead. 
maybe setting `updatedReverations = {}` and using `Object.keys` instead??

Comment: @codenoob I updated the answer accordingly. Please see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this works

```
var arr1 = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "2019-03-27",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": [
            5,
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "2019-03-28",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": "2019-03-29",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "date": "2019-03-30",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "date": "2019-03-31",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "date": "2019-04-01",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": []
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "date": "2019-04-02",
        "time": 1,
        "max_tasks": 3,
        "reservations": [
            3
        ]
    }

]

var arr2 = [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "app": 1,
        "comment": "test 5"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "app": 1,
        "comment": "test 2"
    }
]

for (var i = 0; i != arr1.length; ++i) {
    arr1[i].reservations = arr1[i].reservations.map(id => {
        var reservation = arr2.find(reservation => reservation.id == id)
        return reservation || id;
    });
}
```

It will try to find reservation in array 2 if not it will not replace the id.

Answer (score 0):

below function will give you new copy of merged array.

```
function getMergedArray(arr1,arr2){
return arr1.map(item=>{
    if(item.reservations.length>0){
     let newReservations= item.reservations.map(reservationId=>{
            let foundReservation = arr2.find(reservation=>{
                return reservation.id === reservationId
        })
        if(foundReservation){
            return foundReservation;
        }
        else{
            return reservationId;
        }
     })
     item.reservations = newReservations;
  }

  return item;
});

}
```